# java GUI. keep getting loadImage(): Error: Image at images/f.png could not be found

Tags: java, swing

i am working on hangman game project and i think im done with the code but everytime i load the game it gives me this error which i wrote when it cannot load the images file. im not sure if im doing something wrong to load the directory for the images file. here is the code...
this is ofcourse one of 5 classes but i want to be sure if im making a mistake loading the directory or is it something else. Also if u have any suggestions on how to improve this code im open to that..

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

/**
 * A tile representing a letter to be guessed during a game.
 * @author Jeff A.
 */
public class letterBlocks extends JLabel
{
    /**
     * Add a TileListener
     * @param l The MouseListener to attach as a TileListener
     */
    public void addTileListener(MouseListener l)
    {
        tileListener = l;
        addMouseListener(tileListener);
    }
    /**
     * The directory containing the letter images.
     */
    private final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY;

    /**
     * The type of image (.jpg, .png, etc. to include the period).
     */
    private final String IMAGE_TYPE;

    /**
     * The images of the letters in the window.
     */
    private final char IMAGE_LETTER;
    /**
     * The preferred width of the tiles.
     */
    private final int PREFERRED_WIDTH;

    /**
     * The preferred height of the tiles.
     */
    private final int PREFERRED_HEIGHT;

    /**
     * The current path of the current image.
     */
    private String path;

    /**
     * The current image being displayed.
     */
    private BufferedImage image;

    /**
     * A custom MouseListener from the GameBoard class to change the tiles on
     * a click.
     */
    private MouseListener tileListener;

    /**
     * The default constructor.
     */
    public letterBlocks() { this('A', "C:\\Users\\omare\\Dropbox\\My PC (LAPTOP-AGJUFI2M)\\Desktop\\Images", ".png"); }

    /**
     * Creates a new LetterTile given the letter to be displayed, the directory
     * of the letter image series, and the image type.
     * @param imageLetter The letter to be displayed on the tile.
     * @param imageDirectory The directory holding the letter images.
     * @param imageType The type of the letter images.
     */
    public letterBlocks(char imageLetter, String imageDirectory, String imageType)
    {
        IMAGE_LETTER = imageLetter;
        IMAGE_DIRECTORY = imageDirectory;
        IMAGE_TYPE = imageType;

        PREFERRED_WIDTH = PREFERRED_HEIGHT = 50;

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(PREFERRED_WIDTH, PREFERRED_HEIGHT));
        path = IMAGE_DIRECTORY + IMAGE_LETTER + IMAGE_TYPE;
        image = loadImage(path);
    }

    /**
     * Changes the tile's appearance and removes the mouse listener to prevent
     * the tile from being clicked again.
     * @return The tile's letter.
     */
    public char guess()
    {
        loadNewImage("guessed");
        removeTileListener();
        return IMAGE_LETTER;
    }

    /**
     * Loads a new image in the hangman image series.
     * @param suffix The suffix of the image name.
     */
    private void loadNewImage(String suffix)
    {
        path = IMAGE_DIRECTORY + IMAGE_LETTER + "_" + suffix + IMAGE_TYPE;
        image = loadImage(path);
        repaint();
    }

    /**
     * Remove the tile's TileListener.
     */
    public void removeTileListener() { removeMouseListener(tileListener); }

    /**
     * Loads an image from a file.
     * @param imagePath The path to load an image from.
     * @return A BufferedImage object on success, exits on failure.
     */
    private BufferedImage loadImage(String imagePath)
    {
        BufferedImage img = null;

        try
        {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File(imagePath));
        }

        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            System.err.println("loadImage(): Error: Image at "
                    + imagePath + " could not be found");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return img;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image,
                0,
                0,
                PREFERRED_WIDTH,
                PREFERRED_HEIGHT,
                null);
    }
}
```

i tried to put the images in different files and that didnt work

Comment: When the `path` variable is filled, does it contain what you think it does? Print `path` to the console window once it is filled to make sure the format is correct. Is it missing a directory separator ( `\\ or /` ) before the image file name? Does the image file name contain a proper file name extension (ex: `.png`)?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).